# How to stop Android Studio from opening multiple windows?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, forceclose

I have a Flutter project opened up in Android Studio.
After I import any new package in pubspec.yaml file, A new Android Studio Window pops up that opens up nothing. Just a blank Android Studio Screen.

I cannot close it, If I try to quit, it just closes all the windows together.

Platform: MacOS
Android Studio Version: 3.5

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On Mac, go to System Preferences, General, set `Prefer Tabs` to `always`. Also revert the change to Android Studio preferences System Settings, it will close one project and open another (in the same window).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking into the corresponding setting? (Android Studio -> Preferences -> System Settings)
[image]

Comment: Had tried this too. But nothing happened.
Even tried installing and uninstalling AS, but to no avail.